# Shopify's Traditional Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking Not Passing Data

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, shopify

I'm having a problem with Google Analytics Traditional tracking between my site and my Shopify.com storefront. Ultimatelly, my Analytics account is NOT showing any eCommerce, page-views etc from Shopify.com.

I've conducted a variety of tests between my website and Shopify.com's:

- SetDomainName on both sites:".mysite.com", "mysite.com", "none"
- SetDomainName on MYSITE:".mysite.com", "mysite.com", "none", VS SetDomainName on SHOPIFY:".mysite.com", "mysite.com", "none"
- And every variation in between.

I did have a successful transaction that recorded in my GA account a few weeks ago but I haven't been able to replicate it again (using the same methods you see below, with the same product, using Chrome).

Shopify.com still uses the old traditional Google Anlaytics tracking script so I changed my **GA script on mysite** back to the following trad script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXXX-X');
    pageTracker._setDomainName('.mysite.com');
    pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

And the **inline code from mysite.comis, linking to the Shopify.com store page** (bypassing the shopping cart):

```
<a href="http://mysite.myshopify.com/cart/XXXXXXXXX:X" onclick="pageTracker._link('http://mysite.myshopify.com/cart/XXXXXXXXX:X'); return false;" alt="Buy Product">BUY NOW </a>
```

**Shopify's GA Code** renders as the following and I only have the ability to update the UA ID# and ADD custom variables (as you can see I did with pageTracker and setDomainName below). I CAN'T DELETE or modify the script other than that though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXXX-X');
    pageTracker._addDevId('XXXXX');
    pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
    pageTracker._setDomainName('none');
    try{pageTracker._setDomainName('.mysite.com');}
    catch(e){};pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

As you can see from the Shopify.com receipt page code below, the data I is getting passed and it's registering $, setDomainName twice: once with .mydomain.com and a second with "none". BUT--Unfortunately it's not registering in my GA account.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXXX-X');
pageTracker._addDevId('XXXXX');
pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
pageTracker._setDomainName('none');
try{pageTracker._setDomainName('.mysite.com');
}catch(e){};
pageTracker._trackPageview('/checkout/orders/show');
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pageTracker._addTrans("#1270", "MySiteName", "5.00", "0.00", "0.00", "City", "State", "United States");
pageTracker._addItem("#XXXX", "SYMXXX", "Product Name", "ProjectCategory", "5.00", "1");
pageTracker._trackTrans();
```

Any thoughts?

I'm wondering if the first setDomainName on Shopify.com (that I don't have control of) is negating the second that I've added. I'm going to test what's above without adding the additional "pageTracker._setDomainName('.mysite.com');" on Shopify, but I thought I'd reach out also since my last dozen or so tests have not generated the results I want.

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: I figured it out: setDomainName on mysite to "mysite.com". Leave Shopify SetDomainName to "none". I was stuck on the test that worked with setDomainName with ".mysite.com". This method has worked on 100% of my new tests today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_setDomainName just tells the Google Analytics cookie where to store itself.  It sounds like you're trying to set the domain as `.mysite.com` from a shopify domain like `mystore.shopify.com`.  Cookies can't be set across domains like this for security reasons.  Try leaving `gat._setDomainName('.mysite.com')` on you main site and `gat._setDomainName('none')` on your shopify store.

Comment: Thanks Tom--you nailed it. Tracking ecommerce just fine now.